# Mule 4 : Objectstore : Could not deserialize object

Tags: dataweave, mule4

Scenario : In a Mule 4 app, we are using a maven dependency say MAVEN_DEPENDENCY_APP. The MAVEN_DEPENDENCY_APP is also a Mule 4 application that contains an object store. When running the main app, I am getting the below error :

```
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: org.mule.runtime.deployment.model.api.DeploymentStartException: Error starting application 'testproject'
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.deployment.model.api.DeploymentStartException: Error starting application 'testproject'
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Found error when trying to access ObjectStore
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.exception.DefaultMuleException: Found error when trying to access ObjectStore
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.extension.api.exception.ModuleException: Found error when trying to access ObjectStore
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.store.ObjectStoreException: Could not deserialize object
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.serialization.SerializationException: Could not deserialize object
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.serialization.SerializationException: Cannot deserialize object
```

The object that we are trying to save in the objectstore in MAVEN_DEPENDENCY_APP is as follows:

```
<ee:transform doc:name="Add id to incoming message" doc:id="32e58163-a06a-414b-84a9-c06768e7733c" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
{
    "message-id" : uuid() as String,
    "errorPayload" : write(message.payload,"application/java")
}]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
```

Note : I tried running the MAVEN_DEPENDENCY_APP as a mule project and tested it. It works fine.
Issue is noticed when I use the app as a maven dependency in another mule 4 projects.

Comment: How is the object store configured and where it is accessed? Please add the XML fragments to the question. Is it in the main app or in the dependency? What is the payload exactly? What is the exact Mule 4 version? Also add the complete error message, not the truncated snippet.

Comment: Could you add the object store config  to the question.Also, I hope you are not using a single object store to store/retrieve objects with that are serialized differently(i.e Java and Kryo both)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in packaging the mule application. I used mule-maven-plugin 3.3.5 and provided below configuration :

```
<configuration>
                    <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
                </configuration>
```

It worked

Answer (score 0):

Try Updating the objectStore connector version and runtimeVersion. I was running into similar issues in the past and I believe that fixed it.